# An iframe's vertical scrollbar does not work when the target is a SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint, iframe

**Background**

I have a basic HTML page with an iframe that points to a page with a SilverLight object on it. When the Silverlight object extends past the predefined height, the vertical scroll bar is displayed but in an inactive state. Below is my HTML and screen shots of the iframe.

**Question**

Is it possible to have a vertical scroll bar in an iframe when the target page contains a Silverlight object?

**Code**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <IFRAME height="300" width="1000" name="MyFrame" scrolling="yes"
                    src="http://mycompany.com/mysilverlightpage.aspx">
            </IFRAME>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Screen Shots**

[image: Initial loading of Silverlight object.]

[image: Completed loading of Silverlight object.]

Comment: Can you show the HTML/CSS of the mysilverlightpage.aspx? The layout of the Silverlight object and containing page will have an impact in the iframe (and disabled scrollbars can just be a side-effect).

Comment: I was going to post the code and then I realized that this is a webpart within SharePoint. I made a sample web part without any silverlight and it had the same effect. I'll debug it from this end and let you know the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue had nothing to do with Silverlight but with the SharePoint masterpage hosting the web part that hosted the Silverlight object. To allow the vertical scroll in this case the following changes need to be made to the masterpage. I created a custom masterpage based off for my business needs so I didn't have to worry about these mods wrecking the rest of my environment.

Remove **scroll="no"** from the body tag

Remove the two divs surrounding the "PlaceHolderMain" ContentPlaceHolder

```
<div ID="s4-workspace" class="s4-nosetwidth">
   <div ID="s4-bodyContainer">
      <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ugh.... it is incredibly frustrating that this issue cannot be fixed without creating a new master page. Thanks SharePoint, thanks